# Change tab childcount dynamically

Tags: socialengine

I need to change child count of tab in tab container dynamically.

My requirement,
I created a like widget, it displays title as Like(2)

when I click like button in like widget, I need to update child count as 3.

> class Core_Widget_LikesController extends
>   Engine_Content_Widget_Abstract {   protected $_childCount;   public
>   function indexAction()   {
>       // Get subject
>       $subject = null;
>       if( Engine_Api::_()->core()->hasSubject() ) {
>         $subject = Engine_Api::_()->core()->getSubject();
>       } else if( ($subject = $this->*getParam('subject')) ) {
>         list($type, $id) = explode('*', $subject);
>         $subject = Engine_Api::_()->getItem($type, $id);
>       } else if( ($type = $this->_getParam('type')) &&
>           ($id = $this->_getParam('id')) ) {
>         $subject = Engine_Api::_()->getItem($type, $id);
>       }
>
> ```
> if( !($subject instanceof Core_Model_Item_Abstract) ||
>     !$subject->getIdentity() ||
>     (!method_exists($subject, 'comments') && !method_exists($subject, 'likes')) ) {
>   return $this->setNoRender();
> }
>
> // Perms
> $viewer = Engine_Api::_()->user()->getViewer();
> $this->view->canComment = $canComment = $subject->authorization()->isAllowed($viewer, 'comment');
> $this->view->canDelete = $canDelete = $subject->authorization()->isAllowed($viewer, 'edit');
>
> // Likes
> $this->view->viewAllLikes = $this->_getParam('viewAllLikes', false);
> $this->view->likes = $likes = $subject->likes()->getLikePaginator();
>
> // Comments
>
> // If has a page, display oldest to newest
> if( null !== ( $page = $this->_getParam('page')) ) {
>   $commentSelect = $subject->comments()->getCommentSelect();
>   $commentSelect->order('comment_id ASC');
>   $comments = Zend_Paginator::factory($commentSelect);
>   $comments->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
>   $comments->setItemCountPerPage(10);
>   $this->view->comments = $comments;
>   $this->view->page = $page;
> } else {
>   // If not has a page, show the
>   $commentSelect = $subject->comments()->getCommentSelect();
>   $commentSelect->order('comment_id DESC');
>   $comments = Zend_Paginator::factory($commentSelect);
>   $comments->setCurrentPageNumber(1);
>   $comments->setItemCountPerPage(4);
>   $this->view->comments = $comments;
>   $this->view->page = $page;
> }
>
> if( $viewer->getIdentity() && $canComment ) {
>   $this->view->form = $form = new Core_Form_Comment_Create();
>   //$form->setAction($this->view->url(array('action' => '')))
>   $form->populate(array(
>     'identity' => $subject->getIdentity(),
>     'type' => $subject->getType(),
>   ));
> }
>
> // Hide if can't post and no comments
> if( !$canComment && !$canDelete && count($comments) <= 0 && count($likes) <= 0  ) {
>   $this->setNoRender();
> }
> $this->_childCount = $likes->getTotalItemCount();   }
> ```
>
> public function getChildCount()   {
>       return $this->_childCount;   } }

Comment: what have you done so far on this ? post relevant code.

Comment: I am using default functionality of tabContainer....

I need to override that functionality of on my requirement.